# How to describe 陈省身's name

Tags: characters, character-identification

Shiing-shen Chern, 陈省身 (1911--2004), is a famous geometer.  When taking about him with Chinese people who do not study math and have not heard of him, how can I best describe which characters 陈, 省, and 身 these are?

Yellowbridge has many two-word phrases with 省 and I guess 反省 would be relevant.  But I am not confident whether it would be a good way to explain it.

I guess 身体的身 would work well for 身.

Would 普通的陈 work to say it is the most common name Chen?  Would it sound polite?

I do not think I could draw any of these on my hand well enough for anyone to understand!

Comment: Another suggestion: If the people to whom you talked do not know 陳省身, then you might try to mention the name "華羅庚 (Hua Luogeng)", who was a great analytic number theorist. Prof. Hua was a classmate and a colleague of Prof. Chern and is possibly way more renowned than Prof. Chern in China.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest just explaining the origin:

> 曾子曰：「吾日**三省吾身**：為人謀而不忠乎？與朋友交而不信乎？傳不習乎？」——《論語·學而》
>
> The philosopher Zeng said, "I **daily examine myself on three points**: whether, in transacting business for others, I may have been not faithful; whether, in intercourse with friends, I may have been not sincere; whether I may have not mastered and practiced the instructions of my teacher."
>
> ——"Xue Er" in *The Analects* (Confucianism). Translated in English by James Legge.

So, you can say something like

> 陈是耳东陈，省身是「(吾日)三省吾身」的「省身」。

I think Chinese *should* at least know the idiom `三省吾身(sān xǐng wú shēn)`, if not, it's an opportunity to teach them :)

***PS for pedants***: yes, yes, I know 陈 is not composed of 耳 and 东: 耳 should be 阜/. However in common saying, people just say so and everyone can understand!

Comment: Oh my.  Very nice!

Comment: is there any other chen2 that can be a surname? I thought you only had to break down surnames when there was a possibility of confusion...

Comment: @MasterSparkles  There is no other chen2 nearly as common as this, but there are 谌 and 軙 and who knows how many more rare.

Comment: @S.Rhee just left the PS in case of any challenge on that issue :) I've once encountered that. Anyway in my opinion, pedants' doubt on the standard makes some sense, "if `耳东陈` is acceptable, why is `木易杨` so controversial?" (similarly the doubt is also on 口天吴, 草头黄, etc.)

Comment: @ColinMcLarty 谌 is common, but 軙 as an old variant of 陳 is very probably (if not completely) obsolete now.

Comment: 三省吾身 That is the kind of teaching that kills our poets. We need to re-learn from noble savages to be free, joyful, and overflowing with heath, and above of all, to be spontaneous.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I don't quite get it. What kind of teaching? I believe every language has their idioms. Idioms don't have the power of killing poets.

Comment: I see. You mean teaching the idiom, not the practice.

Comment: 为了把耳部首区分于“阝”部首，后者通常叫做＂双耳部＂。另外尽管部首“阝”实是“左阜右邑” （见比如说http://www.douban.com/group/topic/11816760/ ）可是鉴于＂教学汉字规范手册＂中的＂汉字的部首及部首名称＂列表，该部首无论是左或右只有一个名称即＂双耳部＂（为了区别于单耳部，例字：即、印、却）。

Answer (score 3):

耳东陈 (er3 dong1 chen2)

反省的省 (fan3 xing3 de5 xing3) or 省察的省 (xing3 cha2 de5 xing3)

身体的身 (shen1 ti3 de5 shen1) or perhaps more adequate 捨身的身 (she3 shen1 de5 shen1)

---

For some common surnames, watch [this video](http://kid.chinese.cn/rhymes/article/2011-02/23/content_229522.htm).